# Cannot export tflite model with axios POST method, Error: Request failed with status code 401

Tags: javascript, axios, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-automl

My goal is to use Firebase cloud function export tflite model trained from google cloud automl.

I followed the document from https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/export-edge and **be able to curl export the model smoothly on terminal, but not with axios on cloud function**. With the following code, I got 401 Unauthorized Error, even i set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in .env and require by dotenv package.

My question: Is it possible to export the model with axios POST request? If then what i did wrong?

```
//index.js
require("dotenv").config();

//.env
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="./config.json"
```

```
async function exportModel() {
  const header = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    Authorization:
      "Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)",
  };

  // Construct request
  const request = {
    outputConfig: {
      modelFormat: "tflite",
      gcsDestination: {
        outputUriPrefix: `gs://${output-storage-bucket}/`,
      },
    },
  };

  axios
    .post(
      `https://automl.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${projectId}/locations/us-central1/models/${model_id}:export`,
      request,
      {
        headers: header,
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return error;
    });
}
```

Error

```
Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (/srv/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/srv/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/srv/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to programmatically get the access token. I do not understand how are you trying to get the token with this line of code:

```
 Authorization:
      "Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"
```

Are you trying to run gcloud commands inside Firebase cloud function?

Here you can find information on how to authenticate your request using OAuth2 access tokens

[Google Auth Library Nodejs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs)

Comment: I means gcloud auth application-default print-access-token on terminal then grab the result on terminal and replace that code. Oh do you mean, i need a novel auth token because i'm on node.js env, right?.

Comment: If you use a shortcut and just copy paste the access token it should work. But I still do not understand why do you set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` if you just take the token from console. Run the command using `gcloud` ,  test if it works , and then take the token and use it in your code. It is not the most appropriate way to do it.